# Sending messages to other QThread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyside, signals-slots, qthread

I'm trying to figure out how to implement the concept of having my main thread spawn a new thread that processes data concurrently as messages are passed to it.

From what I figured so far the simplest way of doing this would be something like:

```
from PySide.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QObject, Signal, QThread, QTimer


class Foo(QObject):
    do_foo = Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.do_foo.connect(self._do_foo)

    def foo(self, string):
        self.do_foo.emit(string)

    def _do_foo(self, string):
        # Process string
        print "Process thread:", self.thread().currentThreadId()


class App(QCoreApplication):
    def run(self):
        print "Main thread:", self.thread().currentThreadId()
        thread = QThread()
        foo = Foo()
        foo.moveToThread(thread)
        thread.start()

        # Obviously the following should be done with the event-loop
        # or at doing processing of events.
        running = True
        while running:
            try:
                string = raw_input()
                foo.foo(string)
            except EOFError:
                running = False

        thread.exit()
        thread.wait()
        self.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = App(sys.argv)
    QTimer.singleShot(0, app.run)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But if this would be the way of doing it I can not see what the use of `Slot`s would be.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the design patter "Provider-Consumer". How it works? Well you have to implement a `queue`. The **spwaned thread** will get the data from this `queue` while your **main thread** will feed the `queue` with new data.

[image]

Your spawned threads blocks while the queue is empty. This way you can even process data in more that one thread, and you don't have to worry about two threads trying to read the same data.

Here is some seudo-code for consumer threads.

```
class MyThread:
    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.queue = queue
        self.event = Event()    # I generally use threading.Event for stopping threads. You don't need it here.

   def run():
       while not self.event.isSet():
          data = self.queue.get()   # This stop the thread until new data be available.
          do_something_with_data(data)
```

Then in your `main thread`:

```
import Queue
queue = Queue.Queue()
mthread = MyThread(queue)
mthread.start()

# And now you can send data to threads by:
queue.put(data)
```